# How to use the changed value of dropdown in JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, webforms, web-frontend

I'm having a problem, maybe it would be easy one but for me it has become a headache.

I've a dropdown menu. There it is:

```
<select id="locationSelector" name="locationSelector">
   <option value=0 >All</option>
   <option value=1>Lahore</option>
   <option value=2>Karachi</option>
</select>
```

I get its changed value as follows and want to use its value outside the `on`-callback in a JSON object as given:

```
var loc = 0;
$("#locationSelector").on('change', function(e, loc){
        loc = $("#locationSelector").val();
});

TablesDatatables.condition = {'role.role_id': '2|3', 'location.id': loc };
```

NOTE: I've used `loc` variable in the above object.

But it's not working. Can you please help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe because "location" is in your callback it is being referenced as a local variable. Try changing that callback variable name, I'm not sure what it's used for anyway.

```
var location = 0;
$("#locationSelector").on('change', function(e, locationCHANGED){
    location = $("#locationSelector").val();
});

TablesDatatables.condition = {'role.role_id': '2|3', 'location.id': location   };
```

Comment: David I've changed my code, now can you help me? I'm using 'loc' instead of 'location'. I more thing, if I refresh page, would this loc value be used or vanished?

Comment: On a page refresh you would loose the value. If you want to keep it you would have to track it on the server somewhere in a session variable or a database depending on your requirements.

Comment: thanks for your reponse David, your answer helped me as I didn't know that 'location' is getting used by somewhere else.